# How to express sometimes has one relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

When we ask question in stackoverflow, and somebody answer your question, then the model relationship will be

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

you will take one answer as the best answer of your question, then the relationship is

```
class Question
  has_one answer (the best one)
end
```

but sometimes, question hasn't best answer (such as: no answer is provided)

my question is how to express the relationship between Question an **BEST** answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit superfluous solution, but if you need to implement `(0..1)` multiplicity with standard rails relationship DSL, you may use `through` relation:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_one  :answer, :through => :bestanswers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_one :bestanswer
end

class BestAnswer < Answer
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: thank you and one more question, your solution is `BestAnswer has_one :answer`, how about `BestAnswer belongs_to :answer`, what the difference between two solution do you think?

Comment: The difference is in the direction of relationship (“Use has_one in the base, and belongs_to in the associated model”— http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Ooups, @QiLi, it looks like I messed things up. Sorry for inconvenience; there should be `belongs_to`. I'll make a change in my response.

Comment: JOINS slow for this solution. Also it's not good to separate Answer object apart.

Comment: that means I have to add test_answer_id column to answers table, and add `Answer belongs_to :best_answer` right? because `BestAnswer has_one :answer` and `Answer belongs_to :best_answer` **must** arise together.

Comment: @itsnikolay, Yes, this is not a code-snippet to proud of. But the question was “how to implement (0..1) multiplicity with standard rails relationship DSL” and I know no “more proper” way.

Comment: hello @itsnikolay, you mention _JOINS slow for this solution_, if I hope to get best answer from a question, I must iterate question.answers, right? After adding BestAnswer model, you can get best_answer with two times looking for id (with index). So I guest adding BestAnswer model solution maybe is **faster**, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

```
$> rails g migration add_best_to_answers best:boolean

> a = Answer.first
> a.best = true
> a.save
> q = a.question 
> q.a.best? # => true
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have two questions: 1. If I add best column in answers table, most of answers don't need this column, will it use too much memory or disk? 2. get the best answer from question is difficult. I ever wanted to add test_answer_it to questions table, or add another best_answer_question table. how do you think these two solution.

Comment: 1. in your migration file, set field `t.string :best, :default => false` run 'rake db:migrate`. Don't worry about disk space it's cheap and don't load server processor. 2. If you gonna use the states(steps) for your answers, set :best field to 'string', it also would be good if you rename your :best to :rating (or anything else). Then you can handle all answer states. If you have difficult rating system try to use gem https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: one more question base your solution, if I want to get best answer from question, I have to iterate question.answers, right?